# Induced change of basis on a (p,q) tensor

Tags: summation, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I'm struggling to simplify the last step of a $(p,q)$ tensor and how  its components change with a linear change of basis on the associated vector space. So far I have:

Given a vector space $V$ over some field $F$ with bases $\mathcal{B}=(e_{1}, \dots, e_{n})$ and $\mathcal{B}'=(\overline{e}_{1}, \dots, \overline{e}_{n})$ which are related linearly by a matrix $A=(a_{j}^{i})$

Now let $\alpha$ be a $(p,q)$ tensor on $V$

$$\begin{align}
\alpha = \sum_{{i_{\beta}, j_{\gamma}}}{\alpha_{k_{1}, \dots, k_{p}}^{l_{1}, \dots, l_{q}} e^{i_{1}} \otimes \cdots \otimes e^{i_{p}} \otimes e_{j_{1}} \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{j_{q}}} \\
\alpha = \sum_{{i_{\beta}, j_{\gamma}}}{\overline{\alpha}_{k_{1}, \dots, k_{p}}^{l_{1}, \dots, l_{q}} \overline{e}^{i_{1}} \otimes \cdots \otimes \overline{e}^{i_{p}} \otimes \overline{e}_{j_{1}} \otimes \cdots \otimes \overline{e}_{j_{q}}}
\end{align}$$

From here, I'm trying to find the components of $\alpha$ with respect to the new basis $\mathcal{B}'$:

$$
\overline{\alpha}_{i_{1}, \dots, i_{p}}^{j_{1}, \dots, j_{q}} = \alpha(\overline{e}_{1}, \dots, \overline{e}_{i_{p}}, \overline{e}^{j_{1}}, \dots, \overline{e}^{j_{q}})
$$

$$
=\sum_{l_{{\gamma}, k_{\beta}}}{\alpha^{l_{1}\dots l_{q}}_{k_{1} \dots k_{p}} e^{i_{1}} \otimes e^{i_{1}} \cdots \otimes e^{i_{p}} \otimes e_{j_{1}} \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{j_{q}}} \left(\sum_{\mu}{a_{i_{1}}^{\mu}e_{\mu}}, \dots, \sum_{\mu}{a_{i_{p}}^{\mu}e_{\mu}}, \sum_{\nu}{b^{j_{1}}_{\nu}e^{\nu}}, \dots, \sum_{\nu}{b^{j_{q}}_{\nu}e^{\nu}} \right)
$$

I'm not sure how to simplify this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use multi linearity of the tensor and the facts $e^i(e_k)=\delta^i_k\,, e_i(e^k)=\delta_i^k\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. I've got to $\sum_{l_{{\gamma}, k_{\beta}}}{ \sum_{\delta_{a}} \sum_{\sigma_{b}}\alpha^{l_{1}\dots l_{q}}_{k_{1} \dots k_{p}} a_{i_{1}}^{\delta_{1}} \cdots a_{i_{p}}^{\delta_{p}} b_{\sigma_{1}}^{j_{1}} \cdots b_{\sigma_{q}}^{j_{q}} e^{i_{1}} \otimes e^{i_{1}} \cdots \otimes e^{i_{p}} \otimes e_{j_{1}} \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{j_{q}}  \left( e_{\delta_{1}} , \dots , e_{\delta_{p}}, e^{\sigma_{1}}, \dots, e^{\sigma_{q}} \right) }$, but not sure if its right and how to applying the delta function helps this

Comment: Of course it helps. The monster $e^{i_{1}} \otimes e^{i_{1}} \cdots \otimes e^{i_{p}} \otimes e_{j_{1}} \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{j_{q}} ( e_{\delta_{1}} , \dots , e_{\delta_{p}}, e^{\sigma_{1}}, \dots, e^{\sigma_{q}})$ is by definition a product of $p+q$ Kronecker deltas which considerably simplifies things. I would also recommend to practice that stuff first on a $(1,1)$ tensor. What you are stuck in is just a morass of flamboyant notation.

Comment: @KurtG. would the second and third sums go away just leaving $\sum_{l_{{\gamma}, k_{\beta}}} \alpha^{l_{1}\dots l_{q}}_{k_{1} \dots k_{p}} a_{i_{1}}^{\delta_{1}} \cdots a_{i_{p}}^{\delta_{p}} b_{\sigma_{1}}^{j_{1}} \cdots b_{\sigma_{q}}^{j_{q}} \delta^{\delta_{1}, \dots, \delta_{p}}_{i_{1}, \dots, i_{p}} \delta^{j_{1}, \dots, j_{p}}_{\sigma_{1}, \dots, \sigma_{p}}$, but wouldn't it just be 0 for bigger than a (1,1) tensor. I've got it to $a_{1}^{1} \alpha_{1}^{1} b_{1}^{1}$ for a (1,1) tensor, but it seems the delta's would never be 1 at the same time

Comment: @KurtG. or maybe something like this $\sum_{l_{{\gamma}, k_{\beta}}} \alpha^{l_{1}\dots l_{q}}_{k_{1} \dots k_{p}} (a_{i}^{i})^{p} (b_{i}^{i})^{q}$

Comment: Definitely not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended I consider a $(1,1)$-tensor with summation convention:
$$
\boldsymbol{\alpha}={\alpha^i}_j\; e_i\otimes e^j={\overline{\alpha}^i}_j\; \overline{e}_i\otimes \overline{e}^j\,.
$$
Using
$$
\overline{e}_j={a^\mu}_j\;e_\mu\,,\quad \overline{e}^i={b_\nu}^i\;e^\nu
$$
we get
\begin{align}
{\overline{\alpha}^i}_j\stackrel{!}=\boldsymbol{\alpha}(\overline{e}^i,\overline{e}_j)=
\boldsymbol{\alpha}\Big({b_\nu}^i\;e^\nu,{a^\mu}_j\;e_\mu\Big)=
{b_\nu}^i\;{a^\mu}_j\;\boldsymbol{\alpha}\Big(e^\nu,e_\mu\Big)\stackrel{!}=
{b_\nu}^i\;{a^\mu}_j\;{\alpha^\nu}_\mu\,.
\end{align}
The Kronecker deltas
$$
\overline{e}^i(\overline{e}_j)=\delta^i_j\,,\quad e^\nu(e_\mu)=\delta^\nu_\mu
$$
and so on have been used in the equals signs labelled with $!\,.$ They are the
mechanism that picks the $(i,j)$-th (resp. the $(\nu,\mu)$-th) component of the tensor when it eats
$\overline{e}^i$ and $\overline{e}_j\,,$ resp. $e^\nu$ and $e_\mu\,.$

To show what can go wrong when you don't apply the principle of
summation convention that a dummy index can appear only ***twice***:

For a $(2,2)$-tensor you $\color{red}{cannot}$ write
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\alpha}(\overline{e}_j,\overline{e}_k,\overline{e}^i,\overline{e}^\ell)
=\boldsymbol{\alpha}\Big({a^\mu}_j\;e_\mu\,,{a^{\color{red}{\mu}}}_k
\;e_{\color{red}\mu}\,, {b_\nu}^i\;e^\nu\,,{b_{\color{red}{\nu}}}^\ell\;e^{\color{red}{\nu}}\Big)\,.
\end{align}
Replace the second pair of $\color{red}{\mu}$ and
$\color{red}{\nu}$ by, say, $\sigma$ and $\rho$ and restart.

Comment: So I'm assuming a (2,2) tensor would give $b_{\nu}^{i_{1}}b_{\nu}^{i_{2}}a_{j_{1}}^{\mu}a_{j_{2}}^{\mu}\alpha^{\nu \nu}_{\mu \mu}$ if I've done everything right

Comment: @TheCracker No. Wrong. You cannot have four $\nu$s and four $\mu$s.

Comment: What would the answer be? I was implying 2 sums, 1 over nu and 1 over mu

Comment: @TheCracker You are just guessing. So I am in the edit of the answer guessing what your mistake was and gave another hint. Get out of that morass.

Comment: What about $b_{\nu_{1}}^{i_{1}} b_{\nu_{2}}^{i_{2}} a_{j_{1}}^{\mu_{1}} a_{j_{1}}^{\mu_{1}} \alpha_{\mu_{1} \mu_{2}}^{\nu_{1} \nu_{2}}$

Comment: @TheCracker Still guessing. But this looks better. Derive it with my hints.

Comment: Okay, I've worked it out as best as I could and got $\alpha_{\sigma \mu}^{\nu \rho} b_{\rho}^{i_{1}} b_{\nu}^{i_{2}} a_{j_{1}}^{\mu} a_{j_{2}}^{\sigma}$

Comment: Looks right. One more thing. For tensor components the notation $\alpha_{\sigma \mu}^{\nu \rho}$ is unambiguous *only* when your tensor slots are ordered in the sense that vectors must go into the first $p$ slots. Mostly we have tensors where vector slots and covector slots are totally mixed. Then you need a notation such as $\alpha_{\sigma \mu}{}^{\nu \rho}\,.$

Comment: What would happen when there are more dual basis vectors than basis vectors. As they would form delta functions

Comment: As we know from linear algebra this cannot happen in a finite dimensional vector space. Nonetheless $(2,3)$-tensors exist. Perhaps that should be your next level of the exercise.